# ordered linked list

Tags: sorting, linked-list

I want to build an ordered linked list.

Would it be faster if I sort a linked list as I inserting items into it (ie., see `method #1` below) or would it be faster to just insert all the items then sort them later?

**Method #1**

```
Rough pseudo - code:
for each node in the list
    if newNode is greater than current node
       continue;
    else
       insert the node here;
```

**Method #2**

```
Insert all items.
Sort the list at the end (using QuickSort)
```

Comment: It depends on the sorting algorithm you use.  They all have different performance characteristics.  Inserting new nodes in order requires you to traverse the already existing nodes to find the insertion point for each new node, but that can be sped up by using a hashing algorithm or binary tree.  So again, it depends.

Comment: But sorting the list in the end is pretty painful (since it's a linked list, not an array list), meaning you have to unlink the nodes and move them around, no?

Comment: You're going to have to break at least one link to insert each new item anyway, if you choose to order the nodes as you insert them (unless you're inserting at the beginning or end of the list).

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on the data you are inserting. If you are adding nodes in roughly descending order then obviously it will be faster to sort them as you insert them, but if it's the opposite it will be slower.

It also depends on which sorting algorithm you use if you sort it when it is done.

In general you have more options with doubly-linked lists, when it comes to choices of sorting algorithms.

Also, in some applications it is practical to keep the list sorted at all times so you can query it at any time. If you always add to the head (or the tail) of the list, you'll have to re-sort it every time you add something.

There are also other structures you may want to consider, like binary trees which keep themselves sorted and where the time to add/find a node is logarithmically related to the size of the tree instead of linearly (like the linked list).

Answer (score 0):

Theoratically they are same.

If you choose first(placing thr correct space when you are adding) to find the suitable index it will cost O(log n) with binary search. Consider inserting n elements, you will end up with O(n log n) time.

In second option, after inserting all elements which is O(n) you will sort the array in O(n log n) time with merge sort or quick sort which means O(n) + O(n log n) = O( n log n).

So they cost same complexity but I would prefer first one to avoid the extra inserting time cost.